# Mobile display settings screen size changes in large issue in UI in react native

Tags: react-native

In react native How to resolve if user changes the mobile display settings screen size is larger in mobile phone app UI is affected

```
   Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();
    configuration.fontScale = (float) 1; //0.85 small size, 1 normal size, 1,15 big etc
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    metrics.scaledDensity = configuration.fontScale * metrics.density;
    configuration.densityDpi = (int) getResources().getDisplayMetrics().xdpi;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
```

this code used to if user change the mobile display screen size is large this can be not allowed only default to be maintained so this works only native android if any changes this types working code in react native ?

And i'm changing Androidmanifest  this is also not working